# Convert image To Bytes in Asp.Net Mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In Asp.Net Mvc 6, I am trying to convert image to bytes for adding the picture into database. I cannot find the way to use the right method of encoding. Can someone help me to correct this below code, the mistake is at encoding: UInt32 which is not valid in the given context.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public int UploadImageInDataBase(IFormFile file, PublisherInfos publisherInfos)
    {
        publisherInfos.CoverImage = ConvertToBytes(file);
        var pubInfos = new PublisherInfos
        {
            ImageSize = publisherInfos.ImageSize,
            FileName = publisherInfos.FileName,
            CoverImage = publisherInfos.CoverImage
        };
        _context.PublisherInfos.Add(pubInfos);
        int i = _context.SaveChanges();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

// ConvertToBytes

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
{
    byte[] CoverImageBytes = null;
    var _reader = new StreamReader(image.OpenReadStream());
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(_reader.ReadToEndAsync, encoding: UInt32);
    CoverImageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.Length);
    return CoverImageBytes;
}
```

// Controller

```
 public IActionResult Create(PublisherInfos publisherInfos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files["CoverImage"];
            PublisherInfosRepository service = new PublisherInfosRepository();
            int i = service.UploadImageInDataBase(file, publisherInfos);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                // Add file size and file name into Database
                _context.PublisherInfos.Add(publisherInfos);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = PublisherInfoMessageId.DataloadSuccess });
            }
        }           

        return View(publisherInfos);
    }
```

Comment: Well, where does this `encoding: UInt32` come from and what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Just check out the constructor of BinaryReader and you will understand what you have to pass, using C# syntax.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that the more info the better.  You don't specify what is going wrong.  Does it throw an exception...

Answer (score 4):

You Controller Action will be like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    .....
    .....
    byte[] m_Bytes = ReadToEnd (file.InputStream);
    ....
    ...
    }
```

The Helper Method

```
public static byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

If you are using MVC 5

use this

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile file)
        {
            Stream stream= file.OpenReadStream();
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }



        }
```

Comment: No, that is not the method to code in Asp.Net 5 Mvc 6. Thank you.

Comment: can you give more details regarding your action result and the control you are using?actually it makes no difference weather you code on mvc 6 or 5.For posting a file type we use input type="file" in generic and its an optimum solution though.

Comment: Please see my Repository and Controller above.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
{
   byte[] CoverImageBytes = null;
   BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.OpenReadStream());
   CoverImageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.Length);
   return CoverImageBytes;
}
```